# Unable to compile Java class because the file isn't found

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have  file under classes in tomcat...\webapps.....\classes  named PropertyExample.java

in classes I have a folder called foo in which I have a class person.java

I am importing that person file in PropertyExample.java

and trying to compile PropertyExample.java this below but its showing an error

```
C:\>javac -cp .;"c:\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\jsp\WEB-INF\classes" PropertyExample.java

javac: file not found: PropertyExample.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

Comment: The error says the file is not found.

Comment: the file is there in that folder under classes

Comment: Not from javac' s perspective.

Comment: can you please elaborate what you are trying to say

Comment: The classpath isn't used to find `.java` files. javac isn't locating your .java file because you haven't told it where it is. `.java` files are not usually put in directories called `classes`.

Comment: You really REALLY should get some professional education on working with computers. You should do so BEFORE trying to program one. Your question shows that you are lacking knowledge of file system functions. And not just a little. Get some console education or use an IDE like Netbeans if you don't want to think.

Answer (score 3):

You execute javac the the folder C:\ (root folder). The .java file is somewhere else.
So it can't be found.

The command: `C:\javac Someclass.java` works IF and ONLY IF the file Someclass.java is in the folder `C:\` you wrote that your file is in ...tomcat/webapps/classes (whatever) so you must do a cd to that dir before calling the javac. like this:

```
cd c:\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\jsp\WEB-INF\classes
javac -cp . PropertyExample.java
```

Comment: Your compile command is C:>javac -cp which is in the root folder C:\

Comment: C:\>cd "c:\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\jsp\WEB-INF\classes" javac -cp .PropertyExample.ja
va
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\>

Comment: You are running before you can walk--in all seriousness you should do some java tutorials so that you understand whats going here.

Comment: C:\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\jsp\WEB-INF\classes>javac PropertyExample.java
PropertyExample.java:1: package foo does not exist
import foo.*;
^
PropertyExample.java:12: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Person
location: class PropertyExample
                        Person p=new Person();
                        ^
PropertyExample.java:12: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Person
location: class PropertyExample
                        Person p=new Person();
                                     ^
3 errors

Comment: @DeepakSharma congratulations that means your current problem is solved, because the exceptions you see now mean that the file was initially found (that is a new problem).

Comment: I am trying since morning sir  and i cant move on into chapter because i need to do this

Comment: @DeepakSharma I'm sorry and I don't want to be rude, but what you are trying to accomplish is FAR beyond what you could master. You are trying to solve level 10 of a game, but you haven't even understood the rules yet. I won't tell you what your problem is because if I would tell you like a pupil you wouldn't understand because you lack necessary previous knowledge and if I just give you the solution then you wouldn't learn it. Go back some chapters try something easier first and understand it then come back to this problem. I'm sorry, way to go for you.

Answer (score 2):

The classpath tells `javac` where to find *class files* - not where to find *source files*. You need to give the path name to your source file (either relative or absolute). For example:

```
javac -cp "c:\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\jsp\WEB-INF\classes" 
    "c:\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\jsp\WEB-INF\classes\PropertyExample.java"
```

Of course it would be easier just to change to that directory to start with... or better, to use an IDE or a build system like Ant...